# Pass node command line options to npm executable?

Tags: node.js, npm, command-line-arguments, executable

Does anyone know if it is possible to pass node command line options (e.g. --expose-gc) directly into an npm executable.

I Have a node module that builds an executable (See [here](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#bin)). I want that executable to have access to global.gc(). In order to do this, you need to start your node process with the --expose-gc flag.

I could force users to wrap my executable around a node command but then why do i even need an executable. Thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume your executable file is called `ex`.  First, make sure it's executable by doing `chmod a+x ex` at the command line.  Next, make sure the `ex` file begins with a line like:

```
#! /usr/bin/env -S node --expose-gc
```

[env(1)](https://linux.die.net/man/1/env) will find the node executable on your path, and run it with the given arguments, passing the contents of `ex` into stdin of that process because of the `#!` "scratchbang" at the beginning of the line.

Run your program with just `ex`, or `./bin/ex` (e.g.), rather than `node ex`.

Comment: Adding the "--expose-gc" to the scratchbang throws the following error: /usr/bin/env: node --expose-gc: No such file or directory. Are you sure we can pass command line arguments on the scratchbang?

Comment: This does work. It didn't originally for me because of craziness in how we have node setup as an alias running through docker at my company. Thanks for your help @Joe Hildebrand!! I knew that my executable could run, that wasn't my issue. If anybody has issues here, the key is to add the command line options to the scratchbang!!

Comment: What do you do if you did not create `ex`? This is the typical case. E.g. running mocha, typescript, etc.

Comment: You can pass in node runtime command line arguments by setting the `NODE_OPTIONS` environment variable.  So, `NODE_OPTIONS="--expose-gc" ex`.  See https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v18.x/docs/api/cli.html#node_optionsoptions

Comment: This doesn't seem to work with this specific option: `--expose-gc is not allowed in NODE_OPTIONS`

Comment: Note that many years later, I added `-S` to the call to `env`, so that this will work on Linux.